# php quotes in quote in quotes

Tags: php, quotes

I have the following code:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
iframe0document.getElementById('jform_articletext').value = '<?php echo \"<p align='center'><iframe src='aufgaben/'+cookieValue+'/'+cookieValue+'.html' width='322' height='497' frameborder='0'></iframe></p>\";?>';}</script>";
```

but it has a problem with the quotes, I tried almost everything but it says always:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /usr/www/users/mathea/joomla/plugins/content/DirectPHP/DirectPHP.php(58) : eval()'d code on line 118

Ok the question should be changed to php nesting in php. I need a way to negate the offect of the php nesting like it's possible for quotes with \"

Comment: You are nesting `<?php ?>` _inside_ existing PHP code. That is incorrect and invalid.

Comment: The string you're trying to insert there is just more string... You need to sort out its quoting and escaping.

Comment: Even though your problem seems strange, create a variable called `$quote = '` and use it if you must.

Comment: the second php nesting should only be seen as text which will be set as value of a textbox in an iframe by the javascript, but the quotes and the second php nesting are making problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Updated***

You made PHP tags within `echo`. That's *pretty* wrong!

*As I understand OP:*

```
$text = htmlentities('<?php echo \'<pre><p align="center"><iframe src="aufgaben/"+cookieValue+"/"+cookieValue+".html" width="322" height="497" frameborder="0"></iframe></p></pre>\'; ?>');
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
iframe0document.getElementById('jform_articletext').value = ".$text.";
</script>";
```

You need `htmlentities` function to encode characters to their html equivalents and print out php tags az plain text.

Comment: thank you your token solution seems nice, but I need the 2nd php nesting. It should be seen as text. And my javascript will change a textbox to that text so there is written <?php....?> in the textbox

Comment: @user3125470 please se my update and if it's not your case please clarify your mean of `should be seen as text`. tnx

Comment: the content of the var custom_value should be as follows <?php echo \"<p align='center'><iframe src='aufgaben/'+cookieValue+'/'+cookieValue+'.html' width='322' height='497' frameborder='0'></iframe></p>\";?>';}</script>" because a value of a textbox will become this variable. But php is confused because of the php closing there, I need a way to "disarm" it like for quotes with \"

Comment: @user3125470 Please see my second and third code if it fits your case.

Comment: those are good solutions but the <?php ist still missing at the beginning of $text string and a ?> at the end

Comment: thank you @revo its a good solution only i needed to split the text string at <?php in '<'.'?'.'php... and at the end the ?> and then your solution worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

But you are already in "php mode"!
Why you reopen  php tag on

```
'<?php echo
```

?
Then, what is "iframe0document.getElementById"?

Comment: I need the second php nesting because it shouldn't affect the page at it self it just should be seen as text which is set into an textbox in an iframe by javascript.